# How to count items in Postgresql-database with Django ORM by DateTimeField()

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-3.x, django-queryset

We have a Django application with a Postgresql database. We have a model that contains a `DateTimeField()`.

How do we count the items by hour per day? So that we get something like:

```
July 2, 2016, 4 p.m. | 10
July 2, 2016, 5 p.m. | 12
...
July 3, 2016, 4 p.m. | 7
July 3, 2016, 5 p.m. | 11
```

---

```
# myapp/models.py

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_date = models.DateTimeField()

# myapp/views.py

def object_count():
    query = MyModel.objects.how_to_count_items_by_hour_per_day
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using Postgresql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django 1.10 introduces new database functions ([Extract](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#extract) and [Trunc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#trunc)):

```
from django.db.models import DateTimeField, Count
from django.db.models.functions import Trunc

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    day_hour=Trunc('my_date', 'hour', output_field=DateTimeField())
).values('day_hour').annotate(items=Count('id'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
MyModel.objects.values('my_date__date', 'my_date__hour').annotate(Count('id'))
```

Answer (score 1):

So, until Django 1.10, this looks to be about the best way:

```
jobs = MyModel.objects.filter(my_date__lte=datetime.now()).extra({"hour": "date_trunc('hour', my_date)"}).values(
        "hour").order_by('my_date').annotate(count=Count("id"))
```

The above code is modified from that which is given from the blog that is linked below to group by hour from the `DateTimeField()`

[Django Aggregation: group by day](http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2012/02/24/django-aggregation-group-by-day.html)